# Ethical Hacking/Bug Bounty programs: Best way to get started professionally?

Tags: professional-education, software, career, bug-bounty, software-engineering

I am self-employed (degree in computer science) and I have been fighting a serious illness for the past several years (and still am) which makes it pretty much impossible to take on client projects as my health is just too erratic and unpredictable.

So, I am looking for ways to support myself that can work despite my illness and since I have always had a keen interest in information security, bug bounty programs seem like an interesting option as I can work on my own time, at my own pace without having any client expecting me to meet deadlines.

The problem: Looking around the net and on Safari Books Online, it is hard to really find something structured that gets you started in the right direction with a focus on software security (finding bugs in software, not web sites/applications).

So I would like to ask the community for advice on literature and/or sites, which get one started in the right direction if the focus is on software security and bug bounty programs.

Thanks!

Comment: You have basically asked us to lay out a path to develop the skills, knowledge, and experience to make money finding bugs. This is far too broad of a question to answer. It's like asking, "I want to make money as a freelance programmer, how do I do that?" There are lots of different types of flaws to find in multiple different technologies. And you would be competing with those who do this full time. If you can narrow the focus of your question, we might be able to answer it.